# Insert cropped field length into another table (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to insert a line into TABLE1 from a select from TABLE2. The problem is that one field from TABLE2 is longer than the field in TABLE1. Can I "crop" it and insert just the maximum field length into the target table?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
  SELECT ACT, PROD, DESCRIPTION, ADDRESS FROM TABLE2
```

In table2 DESCRIPTION field is 35 characters long, whereas in the first one it has only 30.

Many thanks!

Comment: Use LEFT(DESCRIPTION,30)

Comment: if LEFT, then LEFT(DESCRIPTION,30) - see my answer

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Answer (score 2):

Why not apply [`SUBSTR`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000854.html) to **DESCRIPTION**? Untested:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
  SELECT ACT, PROD, SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION,1,30), ADDRESS FROM TABLE2
```

That is the same as using [`LEFT`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000817.html) with length 30:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
  SELECT ACT, PROD, LEFT(DESCRIPTION,30), ADDRESS FROM TABLE2
```

Comment: if that helped, then accept it as answer and upvote.